# How can I assign unique anchor tags to each row to return to that row after a page reload in MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view that contains a table of items. In each row of the table, you have the option to click on a link to edit the item which takes you to a different page. I'm trying to make it so that once you finish editing the item and save your changes, it takes you back to the original view but at the same spot.

So, for example, if you had 300 rows in this table and were working with row 247. I click Edit, make some changes, and when I save I'd like to go back to row 247. Instead, I'm brought back to the top of the page after saving. I've seen some stuff for jquery, but isn't there something simple that can be done in razor with anchor tags?

My Code looks like this:

**View**

*Index.cshtml*

```
...
...
...
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>
            <td colspan="5" align="right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.AID })'">Action Event</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Controller**

*DatabaseController.cs*

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.ActionableEvents.ToList());
    }        

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ActionableEvents actionableEvents = db.ActionableEvents.Find(id);
        if (actionableEvents == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(actionableEvents);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AID,Comment")] ActionableEvents actionableEvents)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(actionableEvents).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(actionableEvents);
    }
```

Ideally, it would be nice in my HttpPost for the Edit to do something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index",idtag);
```

where idtag could be a route value that loads the page at the specific anchor tag. Something to the effect of "https://www.mywebsite.com/Home/Index#247".

The question is, how can I append the model.AID value to the anchor tag (or maybe just do something in my  tag) in my for loop and then reference this in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id attribute matching the item id to each row:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="@item.AID"> @* assuming AID is the item id (e.g. 247)*@
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>
            <td colspan="5" align="right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = item.AID })'">Action Event</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Then in your controller set the anchor to the html row's id which should be the same as the item id:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index") + "#" + idtag); // assuming idtag is the item id (e.g. 247)
```

The idtag anchor must match the table row (tr) id attribute to make the page jump to the row.